# How could a Magus cast a Ranger spell at least once or twice per day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a level 1 Magus. I'm planning for them to become an [Arcane Archer](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/prestigeClasses/arcaneArcher.html#_arcane-archer) in the future and wish to use [Bow Spirit](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/bowSpirit.html) abundantly. How could one achieve this? Once or twice per day will do.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method (but an expensive one) would be to purchase a wand of Bow Spirit, which costs 30,000gp. If you are playing in a campaign wherein you can get items created for you (using the Core Rules Magic Item Creation section), you could get an item that could cast the spell twice a day for only a bit more than the wand:

> Command Word/2 Use/day item formula
>   Spell Level: 4
>   Caster Level: 13
>   Base Cost: 1,800
>   Twice/Day: 2.5
>   Total Cost: 4 × 13 × 1,8000/2.5 = 37,440gp

Comment: And by "get a wand" I assume you mean "get a wand and then put a lot of skill ranks into Use Magic Device so you can activate it with a DC20 check?"